# How to mask characters in password textbox? (Excel vba)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that is password protected, code below:

```
Sub close_topic()
Dim open_topics As Worksheet
Dim closed_topics As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim password As Variant
password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password Protected")

Select Case password
    Case Is = False

    Case Is = "password"
Set open_topics = Sheets("HYD-Montering")
Set closed_topics = Sheets("Färdiga_HYD")
i = ActiveCell.Row()

    If i >= 3 And open_topics.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
    j = WorksheetFunction.CountA(closed_topics.Columns(1)) + 2

    closed_topics.Cells(j, 1) = open_topics.Cells(i, 1).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 2) = open_topics.Cells(i, 2).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 3) = open_topics.Cells(i, 3).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 4) = open_topics.Cells(i, 4).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 5) = open_topics.Cells(i, 5).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 6) = open_topics.Cells(i, 6).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 7) = open_topics.Cells(i, 7).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 8) = open_topics.Cells(i, 8).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 9) = open_topics.Cells(i, 9).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 10) = open_topics.Cells(i, 10).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 11) = open_topics.Cells(i, 11).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 12) = open_topics.Cells(i, 12).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 13) = open_topics.Cells(i, 13).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 14) = open_topics.Cells(i, 14).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 15) = open_topics.Cells(i, 15).Value
    closed_topics.Cells(j, 16) = open_topics.Cells(i, 16).Value

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Range(open_topics.Cells(i, 1), open_topics.Cells(i, 20)).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



        Else
        MsgBox "Please select the topic you would like to close first.", vbExclamation

    End If
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
    End Select

    End Sub
```

[Picture of password pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZE58.png)

My question is how or is it possible to mask my password in a format like:
"**********"?

If this was a userform i could change the property "passwordChar", is this doable with VBA code and can it be implemented in my code somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Use a userform, or API calls: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?56817-Vba-code-that-creates-an-input-mask-for-a-password-*****-in-an-input-box

Comment: I thought of creating a userform for this, but if i can avoid that and add 1 line of code to get the achived result i would be happy with that.

Thanks for that link, I will check it out!

Comment: It's a lot more than one line!

Comment: Oh okey i see... Guess I start right away with the userform then. Thank you for you input!

Comment: I studied the code you provided me with in that link and i made it work! Without creating a userform, thanks again!